# Error wikibase return a nil Value

Tags: mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates, mediawiki-installation

When I load a page of my mediawiki instalation, always show me the next message:

"Error de Lua en Módulo:Ficha_de_persona en la línea 35: attempt to index field 'wikibase' (a nil value)."

the system show this information

```
Error de Lua en Módulo:Ficha_de_persona en la línea 35: attempt to index field 'wikibase' (a nil value).
LLamadas de funciones activas (backtrace):
(tail call): ?
Módulo:Ficha_de_persona:35: en la función "chunk"
mw.lua:511: ?
(tail call): ?
[C]: en la función "xpcall"
MWServer.lua:87: en la función "handleCall"
MWServer.lua:301: en la función "dispatch"
MWServer.lua:40: en la función "execute"
mw_main.lua:7: en el campo principal
[C]: ?
```

Comment: Lua modules are user content (they are stored on some wiki page called `Module:...`). You probably copied something over from Wikipedia without setting up the environment it expects (such as attaching the wiki to a Wikibase installation).

Comment: you could tell me or give me a clue as lua is configured?

Comment: Just guessing but you probably need to install the [Wikibase client](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client).